# How to completely deactivate a Bluetooth USB device?

Tags: usb, bluetooth, blacklist

I have a built-in USB device, `lsusb | grep "bluetooth"` outputs:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 413c:8187 Dell Computer Corp. DW375 Bluetooth Module
```

This device has hardware issues, it's not working reliably in Windows either. (It works in Linux after a

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 reset
```

, but after a suspend to ram, the device sometimes completely disappears, sometimes it can not be re-activated, issues, issues...)

I rather use an external Bluetooth dongle, but I do not want to waste battery power on this internal device.

Disabling in BIOS is no alternative, as the BIOS is password protected by company policy. Blacklisting?

EDIT: running latest BIOS firmware

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop bluetooth service

```
$ su -
$ service bluetooth stop
```

To disable bluetooth service on startup

```
# nano /etc/rc.local
```

add this line before exit 0

```
rfkill block bluetooth
```

To disable the bluetooth driver on startup

```
# nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and add this line to blacklist.conf

```
blacklist btusb
```

To cut power source for bluetooth to run

```
# nano /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
```

Change

```
InitiallyPowered = true
```

To

```
InitiallyPowered = false
```

Source: http://namhuy.net/1397/disable-bluetooth-ubuntu-xubuntu-linux-mint.html

Comment: btw: No such thing as `InitiallyPowered` under Ubuntu-MATE 16.04, but the Rest works fine.